# Why does nginx proxy redirect the request?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to pass the API requests to the backend with **NGINX reverse proxy.**

When, I send a get request to */api/testdat*a, it sends a request to *{frontendURL}/api/testData* which, returns with 301(redirect) status code. After that It redirects the request to the correct url *{backendURL}/api/testData*.

[image: Network tab]
[image: network tab 1]
[image: network tab 2]
[image: network tab 3]

nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;



    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    server_name _;

    location /health {
            access_log off;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'application/json';
            return 200 '{"status":"Healthy"}';
    }

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001; 
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

Can I somehow prevent the redirect request so that only one request goes out? Or is this the normal behaviour?

Comment: either tell the real url or share the output of curl

Comment: @djdomi
I can send some picture about the network tab. 
[Redirected request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rq8b.png)
[Request to the redirected url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OUpN.png)
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60S8J.png)

Comment: If I use curl without -L on {frontendUrl}/api/testdata, it doesn't send back anything because the request is just redirected.
With -L, it sends the data back correctly.

Comment: You first request goes to `gwk-frontend`. I guess it's some other server.

Comment: remind to share the output by edit the question instead of using the commantary section ;)